# Nodejs server https running, but socket won't connect (net::ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT)

Tags: node.js, sockets, https, socket.io

I am setting up a nodejs served subdomain so that I can use socket.io. I am serving the page over https, and I got the server to function properly. The page is served. That is not the problem. The problem is when I try to connect the socket to the client. I have been trying to solve this for a while, and I am sure there is a lot of competent people out here that can help me.

This is my site https://reward.cshive.com

**Error message I get:**

[image: Error message]

**Client-side**

```
var socket = io.connect('https://reward.cshive.com:3000');
```

**Server-side**

```
const https = require('https');
var fs = require('fs');
const options = {
  key: fs.readFileSync('/etc/letsencrypt/live/reward.cshive.com/privkey.pem'),
  cert: fs.readFileSync('/etc/letsencrypt/live/reward.cshive.com/cert.pem')
};
var app = https.createServer(options, (req, res) => {
   fs.readFile(__dirname + '/served.html',
  function (err, data) {
    if (err) {
      res.writeHead(500);
      console.log('Error loading page');
      return res.end('Error loading page');

    }
    console.log('--Connection');
    res.writeHead(200);
    res.end(data);
  });
})



var server = app.listen(3000, function(err) {
    if (err) {
        console.log(err);
    } else {
        console.log("Listening on port 3000");
    }
});
var io = require('socket.io').listen(server);
```

Comment: When you say 'The page is served', which page do you mean? I had initially assumed you meant the page mentioned in the code (from the file `served.html`) but I don't seem to be able to access that. I can't get any response out of port 3000, so it could be anything from a proxy or firewall issue to something as simple as the server isn't even running.

Comment: I am sorry, I should have clarified further. What I mean is, the file served.html is served by node. I know this because when I dont do "node server.js" I get a "502 bad gateway" from nginx. I did set a proxy_pass to allow requests over port 3000 in my location block in the sites-available. I will add the config when I get back from school if it helps the case. But, what do you mean by firewall. Which one?

Comment: I haven't tried it myself but this seems like it might be useful to proxy everything through nginx rather than trying to expose Node directly to the world on port 3000 https://gist.github.com/uorat/10b15a32f3ffa3f240662b9b0fefe706

Comment: I'll try it as soon as possible.

Comment: Why not use nginx?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this on your

Put this in the server section, the path to socket.io might change.For me it was /socket.io-client/

```
    location /socket.io-client/ {
            proxy_pass http://node_server;
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
            proxy_redirect off;

            proxy_buffers 8 32k;
            proxy_buffer_size 64k;

            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
            proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
        }
```

And this

```
upstream node_server {
    server 127.0.0.1:8080;
    keepalive 15;
}
```

Also do this

var socket = io.connect(); You wont need to specify host

Comment: Thank you, this wasn't exactly what I needed to solve the problem. But was definitely the major part of the fix

Comment: I would suggest let nginx handle all ssl related stuff and node js be free of it.
As the approach I see you end up doing ssl in both node js as well as nginx.

Might as well let nginx do it.

Comment: Well, I tried creating an http server in nodejs. But the browser will refuse to load resources, because they will be flagged as unsafe.